# Right way to emit events from nested child components in angular 2?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm building a application that has multiple child components and even children of these child components, i'm using the EventEmitter from @OUTPUT decorator to execute functions from father components triggering it inside the child components, but i notice that this is getting out of hand, because everytime i increase a level inside these children, i have to specify this function to use it, what results in a bunch of useless work to get done everytime i need to do it. I'm doing a research to discover if that is really necessary or just useless code being writen.

So, there it is some examples:

```
 functionThatDoSomething(argument){
    return argument;
  }
```

Then, to use that function that do something, i need to pass it to the child component and specify that a event will come in, what would look like something like that:

```
<app-componentchild1 (function)="functionThatDoSomething($event)"></app-componentchild1>
```

In my child component, i would need to declare it:

```
  @Output function = new EventEmitter();
```

Then, imagine that this component is just a list wrapper to child item components, and for some reason i need to use that function inside these item child components, i would need a function to emit that event again so i could use it in another place.

Like:

```
   functionThatEmitMyFunction(argument){
        return this.function.emit(argument);
      }
```

then i would need to put it on html inside a ngfor loop or something like that:

```
<app-componentchild2 (function)="functionThatEmitMyFunction($event)"></app-componentchild2>
```

In the end of this process, i could be able to use (and pass if necessary), any data between these components while executing this action, but is such a boring process that i imagine if it could be done in a better way, using observables or RXJS somehow. Can someone give me any thoughts on this?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. Don't forget that in software architecture, boring is good. Boring is predictable and easy to understand. Bubbling events up to the closest handler component is fine, even though it can be annoying sometimes. Any other implementation will force you to add dependencies to your child components, making them harder to test and making your architecture less clean. There are other solutions if the situation dictates it, but I'd say they're special case use only.`

Comment: I agree with Alexander, if these components are related, it's better to use conventional outputs to raise events. There are scenarios where you want a global event, to handle changes to components that have no relationship, just don't overuse it.